# Table Design Css

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am very new to Bootstrap css, can any one help me to design table header like this, column is seperated by pipe like css

[image]

Below is css .

```
<style>

.table-bordered tbody tr td {
    border: none !important;
}

 .table-bordered tbody tr td input.form-control[type=text] {
        border-radius: 0px !important;
    }

#input_container {
    position: relative;
    direction: rtl;
}

#input_img {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 4px;
    right: 5px;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
}
```

Here i have used "table table-bordered"  class for table and using above css i have removed td border lines

```
    <div class="container">
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Color/Size</th>
            <th>Qty. Needed</th>
            <th>Need By Date</th>
            <th>Special Instructions</th>
            <th>Art Files</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input class="form-control" id="Text1" type="text" /></td>
            <td>
                <div id="input_container">
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="input" value="">
                    <img src="~/Images/calendarImg.png" id="input_img">
                </div>

            </td>
            <td><input class="form-control" id="Text1" type="text" /></td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" />
            </td>
            <td><input class="form-control" id="Text1" type="text" /></td>
            <td><input class="form-control" id="Text1" type="text" /></td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6"><a>Add Rows</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: SO is not for providing solutions!

Comment: I can create table, but column header is seperated by pipe like symbol

Answer (score 1):

I have created a demo for you. Take help and modify as per your requirement.

> ```
> <table frame="box" rules="none" cellpadding="2" cellspasing="5">   <tr style="background-color:yellow; ">
> <td colspan="4">
>   <table style="width:100%">
>     <tr>
>       <td style="width:25%;border-right: thin solid #000;">First</td>
>       <td style="width:25%;text-align:center; border-right: 1px solid #000;">Second</td>
>       <td style="width:25%;text-align:center;border-right: 1px solid #000;">Third</td>
>       <td style="width:25%;text-align:center;">Fourth</td>
>     </tr>
>   </table>
> </td>   </tr>   <tr>
> <tr>
>   <td>
>     <input type="text">
>   </td>
>   <td>
>     <input type="text">
>   </td>
>   <td>
>     <input type="text">
>   </td>
>   <td>
>     <input type="text">
>   </td>
> </tr>
> <tr>
>   <td>
>     <input type="text">
>   </td>
>   <td>
>     <input type="text">
>   </td>
>   <td>
>     <input type="text">
>   </td>
>   <td>
>     <input type="text">
>   </td>
> </tr>
> <tr>
>   <td>
>     <input type="text">
>   </td>
>   <td>
>     <input type="text">
>   </td>
>   <td>
>     <input type="text">
>   </td>
>   <td>
>     <input type="text">
>   </td>
> </tr>   </tr> </table>
> ```

[click here to see it in fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/merajbiswas/nqczmm4d/)

Comment: Thank you Rajesh, I appreciate your help.